# PHP foreach loop only display selected option if a value is selected from top order

Tags: php, html, post, foreach

I have 5 rooms in a table for a guest house and a user must check the room or rooms they wish to book, and select the options they wish to have like the number of people, the breakfast option, dinner option and bed option.

To explain what is going wrong let me give some examples:

Let's say we call the 5 rooms in order of appearance:

> Element Room
>
> Earth Room
>
> Water Room
>
> Air Room
>
> Fire Room

Let's say I check Element room and Earth room with any of the dropdown values, I get the following e.g:

> Element Room
>
> Number of persons: 1
>
> Dinner Course: 120
>
> Breakfast: 70
>
> Bed: King

&&

> Earth Room
>
> Number of Persons: 2
>
> Dinner Course: 200
>
> Breakfast: 70
>
> Bed: 2 Singles

The above does give the correct output.

But now I select just the Water room or any other room that displays below the Element room:

I get:

> Water room (or any besides the Element room)
>
> Number of persons: 0
>
> Dinner Course: 0
>
> Breakfast: 0
>
> Bed: Select Bed Size

If I select each room from the Element room down, I get all the values correctly, but if I select the Element room and then the Air room (not selecting the Earth room) then I get this:

> Element Room
>
> Number of persons: 1
>
> Dinner Course: 120
>
> Breakfast: 70
>
> Bed: King

&&

> Air Room
>
> Number of persons: 0
>
> Dinner Course: 0
>
> Breakfast: 0
>
> Bed: Select Bed Size

It is as if my code will only loop for each value from top to bottom in an order and not other selected values in between, but the rooms checked are always correct, but not the selected options.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="booking-form" name="book-room-form" action="" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>

<?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ) : ?>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="room-selected[]" value="<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>">

<select class="num-person select-update" id="<?php echo 'r-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="people-select[]" required>
  <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
  <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
  <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
</select>

<select class="num-dinner select-update" id="<?php echo 'd-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="dinner-select[]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
    <option value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
    <option value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
</select>

<select class="num-bf select-update" id="<?php echo 'b-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="breakfast-select[]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Breakfast Type</option>
    <option value="70">Basic Breakfast R70</option>
    <option value="120">Full Breakfast R120</option>
</select>

<select class="bed-select" name="bed-select[]">
    <option selected>Select Bed Size</option>
    <option value="King Bed">King Bed</option>
    <option value="2 Single Beds">2 Single Beds</option>
</select>



<?php endforeach; ?>

    <button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-request'])) {

    $room_selected = $_POST['room-selected'];
    $numPeople = $_POST['people-select'];
    $dinnerSelect = $_POST['dinner-select'];
    $breakfastSelect = $_POST['breakfast-select'];
    $bedSelect = $_POST['bed-select'];

    $room = $room_selected;
    $num = $numPeople;
    $dinn = $dinnerSelect;
    $bf  = $breakfastSelect;
    $bed = $bedSelect;

    foreach ($room as $id => $key) {
    //$key returns the room name
      if($key) {
        $result[$key] = array(
            'num_person'  => $num[$id],
            'dinner' => $dinn[$id],
            'breakfast'    => $bf[$id],
            'bed_type' => $bed[$id],
        );
    }

    echo $key . '<br/>' . $num[$id] . '<br/>' . $dinn[$id] . '<br/>' . $bf[$id] . '<br/>' . $bed[$id] . '<br/>' ;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because only checked checkboxes will be transmitted via the Post-Request. So, for example if your Element Room and your Earth Room are checked, you will get:

```
$_POST[room-selected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Element Room
            [1] => Earth Room
        )
```

But if you select any other rooms, the Array will still begin with an index of 0. So to follow your example, if you just select the Water Room, you will get:

```
$_POST[room-selected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Water Room
        )
```

However, the select fields will always give you an array containing all informations, because there always is a value to be transmitted. This means that the first checked room will always refer to the first element of your Select-Arrays.

You could work with string keys for your form to avoid this, e.g.:

```html
<input name="room-selected[<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>]" />
```

You will have to change either your foreach-Loop or your Select-Name-Arrays as well afterwards.